# Edge-Chromium - Registry settings for proxy server does not work immediately

Tags: windows, powershell, proxy, windows-10

I need to switch proxy server settings for edge-chromium with powershell.
The settings will be stored in >>HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings<<.
But after a change the new value does not work immediately.
I need to open >>Settings -> Network and Internet -> Proxy<<. After opening the Proxy settings Edge-Chromium work fine with new Proxy.

```
class ProxyServer {
     [string]$ServerAddress
     [string]$RegistryPath

     ProxyServer(){
          $this.ServerAddress = "newProxy.com:8080"
          $this.RegistryPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
     }
     [void]SetServer() {
          Set-ItemProperty -Path $this.RegistryPath -Name ProxyServer -Value $this.ServerAddress
          Set-ItemProperty-Path $this.RegistryPath -Name ProxyEnable -Value 1
     }
}
```

With Edge(not edge-chromium) and IE the script works fine.
I have tried the Registry hive HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Edge as mentioned [here](https://admx.help/?Category=EdgeChromium&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.Edge::ProxySettings) also.

```
{
 "ProxyMode": "fixed_server",
 "ProxyServer": "newProxy.com:8080"
}
```

But even with this Registrypath I have to open >>Settings --> Network and Internet --> Proxy<<.

testet on Windows 10 1803 and 1909.

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: The registry settings might be cached, which seems to be the case here. Try `netsh winhttp set proxy` instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731131(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#BKMK_5

Comment: @zett42 yes the settings seems to be cached. The NetShell does not work, because I need to change the WinInet Proxy not the WinHTTP. Thanks for your answer